# How to apply attributes with no values to a form using form_start in twig?

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig

I want to give my form a custom attribute "data-abide" using Twig. For instance I want my form to be rendered as:

```
 <form method="post" action="" novalidate="novalidate" data-abide>
```

However the closest I have been able to do is:

```
 {{  form_start(form, {
            'attr': {
                'novalidate': 'novalidate',
                'data-abide': null
            }
        })
    }}
```

which renders:

```
<form method="post" action="" novalidate="novalidate" data-abide="">
```

Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can override default **start_form** block because by default all attributes have key="value" format:

```
<form method="{{ form_method|lower }}" action="{{ action }}"{% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}{% if multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
```

This code works for me:

```
{% block form_start %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set method = method|upper %}
    {% if method in ["GET", "POST"] %}
        {% set form_method = method %}
    {% else %}
        {% set form_method = "POST" %}
    {% endif %}
    <form method="{{ form_method|lower }}" action="{{ action }}" {% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %} {% if attrvalue %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% else %}{{ attrname }}{% endif %} {% endfor %}{% if multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
    {% if form_method != method %}
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="{{ method }}" />
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_start %}
```

This code is important:

```
{% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %} {% if attrvalue %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% else %}{{ attrname }}{% endif %} {% endfor %}
```